# "Prefix 'x' does not map to a namespace"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I want to load a DataTemplate at runtime using `XamlReader`, but it's throwing the exception "Prefix 'x' does not map to a namespace."

This is the XML string I'm passing to `XamlReader`:

```
<xm:ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns:xm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:do="clr-namespace:MyLibrary.DataObjects;assembly=MyLibrary.DataObjects"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
      <xm:DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type do:ValidationResponse}">
        <xm:StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <xm:Label>MessageID</xm:Label>
          <xm:TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MessageID}"/>
        </xm:StackPanel>
      </xm:DataTemplate>
</xm:ResourceDictionary>
```

This is the code that's reading it:

```
ResourceDictionary dictionary = XamlReader.Parse(myXamlString) as ResourceDictionary;
```

Here's the funny part, if I add `x:Key="ValidationResponseTemplate"` to the DataTemplate it parses without any exceptions. I can't keep it that way, however, because I can't specify the DataTemplate by key in the program's own `.xaml` (it won't know about the template until it gets fetched at runtime).

The `x` namespace is defined in both the program's own `.xaml` and in the fragment of XML I'm trying to parse.

Overall objective: be able to provide new DataTemplates to both change the appearance of the display at runtime, and to display XML data that the client did not know about at compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way around it: rather than have `XamlReader` parse a string, it worked better if I gave it an `XmlReader`. The fragment of XML with the `DataTemplate` defined in it was part of a larger XML document that had all its namespaces defined in its root. This had already been read into an `XDocument`, and out of which I'd grabbed the `XElement` with the `ResourceDictionary` defined in it. The new code, part of `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, looks like this:

```
ResourceDictionary dictionary = XamlReader.Load(myXElement.CreateReader()) as ResourceDictionary;
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
```

This threw a different exception, where it couldn't resolve the type of `(http://myschemas/MyProfile)Binding`. It turns out that you need to qualify the namespaces of *everything*, including the `{Binding ...}` references. So the XML fragment had to be amended to:

```
<xm:TextBox Text="{xm:Binding Path=MessageID}"/>
```

Now XamlParser knew that `Binding` was a type in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com..." namespace.